# Как на android покрыть всю ширину экрана

Tags: android, html, javascript, css

Как на android покрыть всю ширину экрана, через html + css + js. В версии 4.0 работает нормально, в 2.0 появляется какая-то белая полоса, где должен быть скроллбар

Фишка в том, что в вариантах.

1) Браузер и денвер

2) Денвер и браузер смартфона 
все норм отображает, а когда HTML+CSS+JS компилят получается такое гов..
[image]

```
     body{
      widht: 100%;
      //....
      overflow:hidden;
      background-image: url(../picture/fon.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

Comment: в том числе и софтварные кнопки внизу?

Comment: а где пример, что бы подсмотреть на реальном устройстве?

Comment: пример не разрешают давать( ну смотрите просто ширина не высчитывается нормально.
Но на 4ом андроиде работает ок, а на 2ом не ок. 
overflow:hidden; 


так-же в обработчике стоит

 document.body.style.width = document.documentElement = screen.availWidth

Comment: ну я понимаю, секретность и тому подобное. А сложно сделать на коленке минимальный пример и выложить на каком-либо народе/укозе?

Но раз нельзя,  значит придется самому Вам делать.

Comment: @KoVadim вот обновил, заметьте, что в 4.0 все нормально работает, а в 2.0 появляется бела полоска

Comment: ох ужасно обновили. ужасно. Текст ужасен, картинка плохая.

[здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279978/webview-showing-white-bar-on-right-side) народ обсуждает такую же проблему.

Comment: Блин с моим знанием Англ.яз. Я так понял, что в widndow.onload надо вбить webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блин с моим знанием Англ.яз. Я так понял, что в widndow.onload надо вбить
`webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);` ?

эту строку нужно самому виджету в андроид-приложухе вписать. чтобы места для полосы прокрутки не давалось, а не код сайта менять.

Comment: Да именно так - слава Б*гу, что есть люди которые знают/соображают - молодец!